# Can't send "Authorization" header to endpoint - HTTP Module - Mulesoft 3.9

Tags: mule, basic-authentication, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to call an API Rest from a flow in mule. This API has a basic auth protocol, so I need to send the header "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX".
The issue that I encounterd is that on the Anypoint Studio, when I'm cofiguring the HTTP Request, I don't get the option of Basic Auth on the Authentication tab, I only see NTLM.

- I already tried to set the header manualy, But it gets ignored.
- Already tried to include this:

  < http:basic-authentication username="${ofsc.clientId}@${ofsc.instance}" password="${ofsc.clientKey}"/>

on the http:request-config, and it didn't work either.

This is the Mule config:

```
< http:listener-config name="Gateway" host="localhost" port="8281" basePath="/base" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

< http:request-config name="OFSC" host="api.etadirect.com" basePath="/rest/ofscCore/v1" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" port="443" protocol="HTTPS">
    < http:basic-authentication username="${ofsc.clientId}@${ofsc.instance}" password="${ofsc.clientKey}"/>
< /http:request-config>

< spring:beans>
    < spring:bean id="Bean" name="BasicAuthEncode" class="tools.BasicAuthEncode" />
< /spring:beans>

< context:property-placeholder location="env.properties"/>   

<flow name="TestFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="Gateway" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:response-builder disablePropertiesAsHeaders="true"/>
        <http:error-response-builder disablePropertiesAsHeaders="true"/>
    </http:listener>
    <invoke object-ref="BasicAuthEncode" method="encodeCredentials" doc:name="LPM" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String" methodArguments="${ofsc.clientId}@${ofsc.instance}:${ofsc.clientKey}" name="LPM2"/>
    <set-variable variableName="credentials" value="Basic #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Creds"/>
    <http:request config-ref="OFSC" path="/activities/3818" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="200,400,401,404,403"/>
    </http:request>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

I'm probably doing something relly wrong, but couldn't find the answer. Hope you guys can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on my properties file.

The values where wrapped in quotes, and the base64 encoding was giving me a wrong string.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the "enable cookie" in the http configuration resolved the issue.